Configuring Okta to complete MFA challenges
I am an administrator for a volunteer organization that is consolidating our organizations passwords from several password management services (bitwarden, lastpass, etc) into one okta identity engine domain. I am attempting to configure applications such as Cloudflare, for instance, that require an MFA challenge to complete log in. I have had difficulty with finding relevant documentation for this task, and am looking for documentation and examples of successful MFA configuration.
I have sought documentation in the Okta identity engine knowledge base, and have only found instructions for enrolling users in MFA to access Okta, not applications.

Have you enabled SSO of your app (Cloudflare) with Okta? If so, then it's just a matter of creating a proper application authentication policy in Okta, requiring MFA for your app
